# PHP imagecreatefrompng

Tags: php, image-processing

I am using imagecreatefrompng in the following code. Any code that runs after the call to that method does not execute and the loop exits. No errors are thrown at anytime. If I comment out that line, the loop executes and all images are rendered in html. I have GD2 enabled as well as fopen wrappers. I can also try..catch the whole block, but no errors are thrown. I have also tried suppressing errors with "@" but that doesn't work either.

```
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
<?php
$qs = $_GET['stack'];
$stack = explode(" ", $qs);
foreach ($stack as $filename)
{
?>
    <img src="../content/images/trays/<?php echo "$filename.png"; ?>" alt="" />
<?php
    $img = imagecreatefrompng("../content/images/trays/$filename.png");
    echo "works: $filename.png";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

php.ini memory_limit: 128M

Comment: Are you sure errors output to the browser? `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');`

Comment: Also, what is your `memory_limit` in php.ini set to?

Comment: @brian_d you are correct, I was not outputting errors to the browser. Coming from the asp.net world, I was making the assumption it would do that without me needing to set anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking if you can open the file:

```
$img = @imagecreatefrompng("../content/images/trays/$filename.png');
echo $img ? "Works: $filename.png" : "Could not open file to create PNG from" ;
```